# extract nested dictonary from String data[PYTHON]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary `data`, which has a key`message` and value is `string`.

the value in the dictionary is a combination of string + inner-dictionary.

I want to extract inner-dictionary as a separate dictionary.

**Example-input**

```
data = {'message': '[INFO]-processed-result - {"customer_id": "cust_111","user_ids":[1,2,3],"collection":{"default":"def_1"}}'}
```

**Example_output**

```
output = {"customer_id": "cust_111","user_ids":[1,2,3],"collection":{"default":"def_1"}}
```

**I don't want to use python SPLIT**

**Can anyone suggest solution for this?**

Comment: "I don't want to use python SPLIT" Why not? It looks like you could split the message from the first ` - ` and then parse the rest with with `json.parse()` or `ast.literal_eval()`?

Comment: @AKX, the string before the(`[INFO]-processed-result -`) the dictonary not always same. thats why i said, i dont want to use SPLIT

Comment: Consider showing more examples so that we would be a little clear of what you are talking about from your comment :  *the string before the([INFO]-processed-result -) the dictonary not always same*

Comment: @JenilDave,Please see this input example `data = {'message': '[INFO]-processed-result-2020-10-01T23:45:49.472Z- {"customer_id": "cust_111","user_ids":[1,2,3],"collection":{"default":"def_1"}}'}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using `index` method of `str` and using inbuilt `eval`

```py
>>> data = {'message': '[INFO]-processed-result-2020-10-01T23:45:49.472Z- {"customer_id": "cust_111","user_ids":[1,2,3],"collection":{"default":"def_1"}}'}
>>> index = data['message'].index('{')
>>> output = eval(data['message'][index:])
>>> output
{'customer_id': 'cust_111', 'user_ids': [1, 2, 3], 'collection': {'default': 'def_1'}}
>>>
>>> data = {'message': '[INFO]-processed-result - {"customer_id": "cust_111","user_ids":[1,2,3],"collection":{"default":"def_1"}}'}
>>> index = data['message'].index('{')
>>> output = eval(data['message'][index:])
>>> output
{'customer_id': 'cust_111', 'user_ids': [1, 2, 3], 'collection': {'default': 'def_1'}}
```

You can also consider using `json.loads()` for a faster solution

```py
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(data['message'][index:])
{'customer_id': 'cust_111', 'user_ids': [1, 2, 3], 'collection': {'default': 'def_1'}}
```

Comment: Here's hoping the message never contains `{"message": __import__('os').system('rm ...')}`– *don't use `eval()`.*

Comment: @AKX yes using `eval()` is risky that's why I gave an alternative to it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply search for the first `{` and use indexing to get the location of the dictionary within the string.

```
import ast

index_dict = data['message'].find('{')
output = ast.literal_eval(data['message'][index_dict:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Regular Expressions:

```
import re
import ast

data = {'message': '[INFO]-processed-result - {"customer_id": "cust_111","user_ids":[1,2,3],"collection":{"default":"def_1"}}'}
output = {"customer_id": "cust_111","user_ids":[1,2,3],"collection":{"default":"def_1"}}

message = re.findall(r'^\[INFO\]-processed-result - (.*)', data['message']).pop()
output = ast.literal_eval(message)
print(output)
```